# how to exit application from custom dialog activity?

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have main activity which opens a custom dialog . Dialog has a button which takes you back to the main activity . Now when i press back button when dialog is open i want to exit the application instead of going to the main activity , but back button just closes dialog & takes me to main activity. 
I tried using process kill ,

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

but no use . Please help.

Answer (score 0):

set a [onCancelListner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnCancelListener.html) to dialog and call `finish()` inside `onCancel` method
here is a sample

```
AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    b.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            finish();
        }
    }).setTitle("hello").setMessage("messgae 1").setPositiveButton("ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
    }).setNegativeButton("cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
           //call finish() if needed
        }
    }).create().show();
```

Comment: can't attach a listener since i want application to finish only when dialog is open & backpressed . but if i attach a listener for dialog cancel then whenever i click on the button in  the dialog which takes to the main activity it will unwantedly finish the application.

Comment: no , onCancelListner will finish only if you cancel the dialog, hope you are not setting onDismissDialogListner

Comment: well u guessed it right for so long i have been trying with ondismisslistener , thanx a lot u helped me a big tym :) .

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but you can override the onBackPressed method of Activity and call finish in there. Just have some boolean to check if the Dialog is showing currently. If yes then finish the activity.

Answer (score 0):

You should first finish your Activity on `Dialog` Button click using  `finish();`and then use following code in `onDestroy()` of your activity.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    super.onDestroy();
}
```